# need help in c making a calculator

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"

int main(void)
{
        /* varibles */
        float a[3];
        char operation;
        int num;

        /* header print */
        printf("Enter the operation you would like to use\n");
        scanf("%c", &operation);

        /* ifs */
        if(operation == "*") //warning is here
        {       
                printf("How many numbers would you like to use (max 4)\n");
                scanf("%d", &num);

                switch(num)
                {
                        case 2:
                                printf("enter your numbers\n");
                                scanf("%f", &a[0]);
                                scanf("%f", &a[1]);
                                printf(" the answer is %2f %2f", a[0] * a[1]);
                        break;
                }

        }
}
```

Whats the problem?
i get this error

```
Calculator.c: In function 'main':
Calculator.c:16:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Why wont it complile please help.
help fast now please

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Ah, the wonders of the alt key. Line numbers gone in a flash.

Comment: And how do i compile it without a error?

Comment: @chris harder to find line 16 now though :(

Comment: @user1952761, I'll pretend you said warning, but you read it, study it, fix it, and get acquainted with it so that next time it pops up, you instantly know what to look for. I must admire your determination in getting rid of the warnings, though. Keep that up.

Comment: @KarthikT, Good point, sorry. I added a comment there (and got rid of the duplicate lines of code at the top, so the line should actually match now).

Answer (score 5):

Try to change

```
operation == "*"
```

to

```
operation == '*'
```

This could be your issue since a string literal ("*" with the double quotes) is a `const char *` (the pointer) while `operation` is a `char` (the integer). There is your warning.

It is good you are fixing this because if you ignore it, you will get wildly wrong behaviour( pretty much always false) since you are comparing a character with a pointer to a string with a character, and not two characters as you would expect.

p.s - another error (not compiler but possible runtime) as pointed out by @WhozCraig, your printf has 2 specifiers(`%2f`) but just 1 variable. This is gonna result in undefined behavior at best.

Fix as :

```
printf(" the answer is %2f", a[0] * a[1]);
```

Comment: Perhaps fix this: `printf(" the answer is %2f %2f", a[0] * a[1])` as well, since its undefined behavior passing a format string with two specifiers and only one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `operation == "*"` with `operation == '*'` because **single quotes** are for *characters* and **double quotes** for *strings* and obviously, you are checking for character equality.